# Is there any way to position a vertical border exactly between 2 left-justified paragraphs?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have 2 fluid, Foundation columns with text in them, side by side.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.4/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="column medium-6">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="column medium-6 border-left">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

There is padding around the text and it is left justified. I want to put a dividing border between them, but of course, with the text justification, I get a lopsided look as below:

[image]

I've tried messing around with padding, but this isn't responsive.

Is there any technique or way I can have the the border appear centered at all screen widths?

Answer (score 0):

Give outer container 100% width and for inner container give the percent width in which want to sub divide outer container. And Apply left border css to last inner container.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
     Content
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="border-left: 1px solid grey;">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I have. Foundation works exactly like Bootstrap (medium-6 = 50% as col-md-6 =50%)